# Mapping of generic classes in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have following classes in a Java Hibernate project:

```
@Entitiy
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class ClassA<T extends ClassB>{

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mycolumn_id")
    private T instance;

[...]

}


@Entitiy
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ClassB{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer id;

[...]

}
```

When I try to create/save an instance of ClassA (with an instance of a class which inherits ClassB) I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property ClassA.instance has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
```

I can't set an explicit target to "T instance" in ClassA because ClassB is abstract and the literal "T.class" is not valid. However the generic usage is necessary because I have to save many different types of ClassB in ClassA.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you use `targetEntity=ClassB.class`? Is it only because ClassB is abstract? Can you just make ClassB concrete, and prevent direct instatiation with a protected constructor?

Comment: I can use "targetEntity=ClassB.class" but this will get me an exception at runtime which says "cannot instantiate ClassB". Hibernate tries to instantiate ClassB instead of the concrete class which is a little bit confusing. So it is no difference if I try it with an protected constructor.

Comment: I have to correct me. The abstract constructor of ClassB will NOT result in an exception. But that doesn't solve my problem because it will create an entry of ClassB and not of the concrete class.

Comment: How hibernate has to create foreign key in your case? I think you cannot do 'dynamic' mapping in hibernate(if i'am wrong correct me please). Maybe if you set ClassB inheritance as SingleTable then hibernate will know with which table ClassA is related and create foreign key for it.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of testing, trying to get Java parameterisation working with an abstract parent (Single-table inheritance), and an abstract child table (one-table-per-class inheritance), I've given up.

It may be possible, but often you get problems where Hibernate tries to instantiate an abstract (parameterised) class as an entity.

I would suggest rewriting it using the JPA inheritance, moving the parameterised stuff down into extending classes.  That way you get the same polymorphism back from the database.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CLASS_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class ClassA {

  [...]

}
```

extension B:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue=("B")
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mycolumn_id")
  private Integer instance;

  [...]
}
```

extension C:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue=("C")
public class ClassC extends ClassA {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mycolumn_id")
  private String instance;

  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from hibernate trying to create an entity from an abstract class (either specified as 'abstract', or using the Java parameter).

You need to create an abstract base class, which is NOT an entity, and then extend that for specific types.  Your subtypes can add columns which are nullable in the table, and/or specify the parameter.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TRACK_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class ClassA<T extends ClassB>{

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mycolumn_id")
    private T instance;

[...]

}
```

You also need to decide whether ClassB is extending ClassA, or is a related table.  You can't have B extending A, but use a different inheritance type.
Assuming Single-Table:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue=("B")
public class ClassB extends ClassA<Integer>{

  [...]

}
```

Comment: This will give a warning:  
``WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - HHH000503: A class should not be annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass. @Inheritance will be ignored for: ...``

Comment: Yes, it does give that warning now... I've just noticed similar warnings on my project.  I suspect Hibernate has changed something since this post.  Will update when I get the chance.